# Is there a way to darken an image except for a rounded rectangle in ImageMagick?

Tags: imagemagick

To demonstrate.

Original:
[image: Original Image]

After ImageMagick:
[image: Edited Image]

I have some ideas:

- Duplicate the image, crop the duplicate, then flatten the images together
- Reverse mask?

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in Imagemagick by darkening the whole image, creating a round rectangle mask image, then composite the original with the darkened using the mask image.

Input:

[image]

```
convert pasta.jpg \
\( -clone 0 -brightness-contrast -75,0 \) \
\( -clone 0 -fill white -colorize 100 -fill black -draw "roundrectangle 20,20 80,80 15,15" -alpha off \) \
-compose over -composite \
pasta_rect.jpg
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: you are incredible. This is a perfect solution. Funnily enough I was just browsing your list of scripts here: http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick as you answered this. I am honoured to receive your reply 

Answer (score 2):

Although this has been successfully answered, I'll offer another simple approach using IMv6...

```
convert pasta.jpg -fill white \
   \( +clone -evaluate set 25% -draw "roundrectangle 20,20 80,80 15,15" \) \
   -compose multiply -composite result.png
```

After reading in the input image, in parentheses it clones the input and uses `-evaluate` to set the entire clone to 25% gray. A white "roundrectangle" is drawn on that gray image in the area you want to preserve. The mask looks like this...

[image]

Then after the parentheses, that mask and the input image are composited with `-compose multiply`. That leaves the white rectangle area as it was in the original input, and the rest of the image is multiplied by  0.25, leaving it darkened. The result...

[image]

This command should work just the same in IMv7 by changing "convert" to "magick". And it should work as well on Windows CLI by changing the continued-line backslashes "\" to carets "^", and removing any backslashes before the parentheses, so this "\(...\)" to this "(...)".

Comment: Another great approach, thanks @GeeMack